# How to apply minimal changes to the GUI in javaFX

Tags: java, javafx, fxml, scenebuilder, fxmlloader

Is there a preferred way to apply (small) changes to a GUI in javaFX? I prefer using FXML instead of doing it programmatically.

For example: The application starts up with a background and some buttons in a VBox (they are arranged like its defined in a FXML file).

Let's assume that an user presses a button (e.g. in a game the button is named "multiplayer") so the GUI has to change to display the next step.

In this example I like to achieve that the button is named something else, another button to be replaced with a text field and maybe some other small changes will be applied. But most of the GUI will stay the same e.g. the background, the VBox itself and some buttons.

Should I apply these changes programmatically using something like `vbox.getChildren().remove(button);` and `vbox.getChildren().add(textField);`? But why use FXML then? I could do the whole GUI programmatically instead of only loading the starting fxml scene and then apply changes programmatically.

Or should I load a new scene from a different FXML file where these changes are made inside the FXML file. But then I notice that my application needs a long time to load the new FXML file via FXMLLoader and displays a white screen for a short time.

Or should I split my FXML file into different layers so I can e.g. only exchange the VBox with another VBox instead of replacing the whole GUI? But how should I structure my GUI then, and can I still use SceneBuilder?

Probably all my ways are not the preferred ones. So how can I achieve my aim in a good way?

If you want to take a look at my current code, I posted it in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41314300/transparent-stage-scene-loses-its-transparency-after-loading-another-fxml-file/) earlier.

Comment: I would define the views as the smallest individual components, and when something like what you described happens, swap parts of the view with another. Let's say you have a `MainButtons` and a `MultiplayerButtons` component. Once you click the multiplayer btn on main, just swap main to multi.

Comment: So your suggestion is to have an own fxml file for each component like a button? Or did I understand that incorrectly? And how can I build my complete GUI out of those files?

Comment: For the text change, the preferred way is using a controller. Removing should also be done there, but it's a little more complicated.

Comment: @MouseEvent And what should I do when I want to replace the button with something else?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of defining a `Button` or a `TextField` in the fxml, define a container there, for example a `Pane`. Then change what has to be inside this `Pane` in your controller:

```
@FXML 
private Pane flexiblePane;

private Button myButton = new Button();
private TextField myTextField = new TextField();


private void displayFlexiblePaneAsButton(boolean flag) {
    if (flag) {
        flexiblePane.getChildren().clear();
        flexiblePane.getChildren().add(myButton);
    }
    else {
        flexiblePane.getChildren().clear();
        flexiblePane.getChildren().add(myTextField);
    }
}
```